# Meaning of news headline

Tags: headlinese

What is the meaning of this headline? I got it from [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2013/05/changing-chaparral).

> Difference Engine: Circle of life

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, a [Difference Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) is *an automatic mechanical calculator designed to tabulate polynomial functions* (the primary association being [Charles Babbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage), who built the most famous early one).

But in OP's context, it's the name of an occasional column in The Economist. Initially I thought the column might be excerpts from [an alternate history novel by William Gibson and Bruce Sterling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Difference_Engine), but apparently not (see below). But here are the titles of some instances of the column I found with no trouble...

> [Difference Engine: The caring robot](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2013/05/automation-elderly)
>    [Difference Engine: Unplugging the cables](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2013/04/gigabit-wi-fi)
>    [Difference Engine: Circle of life](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2013/05/changing-chaparral)

The "Circle of Life" part simply refers to the natural cycle of vegetation being burnt and recovering. That's a matter of concern in California today, where for many decades the authorities have been actively trying to prevent/extinguish forest fires. It now seems that interfering with the natural cycle in such ways may create more problems than it solves.

---

The Economist has a column/blog called [Babbage](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage), where the "about" link leads to ***About Babbage:*** Reports on the intersections between science, technology, culture and policy, in a blog named after Charles Babbage, a Victorian mathematician and engineer.

Taking that into account, when OP actually reads the article itself, s/he should assume that all references to "Babbage" in the text actually mean "the author of this column".